# Rename batch files in bulk using spaces?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

You can rename files in batch in bulk using, for example:

```
rename *.docx *.pdf
```

However, when my docx files have spaces in them, this renames them to new files which only have the first word in their file name. How do I preserve the entire file name?

EDIT: Apparently this is only the case when the file name as a dot in it (but the file has no extension still), for example:

```
2017. abcdef
```

Comment: Works quite happily for me. Please give some examples of failures.

Comment: @Magoo seems to be only in specific circumstances; added a use case

Comment: Your use case makes no sense as it doesn't match the required `docx` extension. Otherwise quote the names `rename "*.docx" "*.pdf"` This is a bit OT and better asked in [SU].